# Group by at multiple node at once in xslt

Tags: xslt, group-by

Below is the input xml structure-

```
<root>
    <Entry>
        <id>id1</id>
        <Line>
            <tax>tax1</tax>
            <amount>13.00</amount>
        </Line>
        <Line>
            <tax>tax2</tax>
            <amount>4.00</amount>
        </Line>
        <Line>
            <tax>tax2</tax>
            <amount>2.00</amount>
        </Line>
        <Line>
            <tax>tax4</tax>
            <amount>8.00</amount>
        </Line>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
        <id>id1</id>
        <Line>
            <tax>tax2</tax>
            <amount>15.00</amount>
        </Line>
        <Line>
            <tax>tax3</tax>
            <amount>35.00</amount>
        </Line>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
        <id>id2</id>
        <Line>
            <tax>tax2</tax>
            <amount>12.00</amount>
        </Line>
            <Line>
            <tax>tax2</tax>
            <amount>22.00</amount>
        </Line>
        <Line>
            <tax>tax1</tax>
            <amount>5.00</amount>
        </Line>
    </Entry>        
</root>
```

I want to get the output as below structure-

```
id1, tax1,  13.00
id1, tax2,  21.00
id1, tax3,  35.00
id1, tax4,  8.00
id2, tax1,  5.00
id2, tax2,  34.00
```

I tried to implement the below logic. but it didn't work.
forEach Entry  groupBy id
forEach distinct(id) groupBy tax

Can someone please help me with the xslt transformation?

Comment: Is your input really text with some markup like what you posted?

Comment: input is XML. I didn't mention with proper xml tag

Comment: Then please post your exact input and output structures.

Comment: Do a search - [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info) is probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. -- P.S. The input you show is not XML and cannot be processed by XSLT.

Comment: Hello, I have now corrected the input XML. can you please me with the xslt now.

Comment: First tell us which version of XSLT your processor supports. Then show us your XSLT attempt. Then ask for help.

Comment: Your input has two nodes with id=id1, tax=tax2, and the corresponding values are 4.00 and 2.00. Your desired output has 21.00. I fail to see how you combine 4.00 and 2.00 to get 21.00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following XSLT 2.0 stylesheet uses [`xsl:for-each-group`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#xsl-for-each-group) to group the `amount` by a composite key of their `id` and `tax` values concatenated, calculates the [`sum()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-3/#func-sum) of the grouped `amount` and uses [`format-number()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-3/#func-format-number) to ensure two decimal places.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="/root/Entry/Line/amount" group-by="string-join((../../id, ../tax), '-')">
            <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../id, ../tax, format-number(sum(current-group()), '#.00')" separator=", " />
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Looking at the sample values, I wonder whether, if you do sort, using `<xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" collation="http://www.w3.org/2013/collation/UCA?numeric=yes"/>` makes sense, as that way e.g. `id10` would sort after `id5` while the default Unicode collation sort would sort it before it. And I am not sure whether XSLT 2 you have suggested supports that collation, I think it is only introduced in XSLT 3.

Comment: Try it and post an alternate solution. The more the merrier!